Как проверить комбинации покера?
Делаю покер на Python, возник вопрос как определить комбинации, если у меня колода карт составлена вручную и состоит из строк. Дело в том, что у меня есть 5 основных списков: колода, карты игрока (2 карты), карты компьютера (2 карты), флоп, использованные карты. Из-за чего становится трудно определить комбинацию, ведь уже код плотно связан с ними. Как мне на этапе флопа определить комбинации у каждого игрока, если нельзя использовать функций Python?
koloda = ["♠️A", "♠️K", "♠️Q", "♠️J", "♠️10", "♠️9", "♠️8", "♠️7", "♠️6", "♠️5", "♠️4", "♠️3", "♠️2",
      "♣️A", "♣️K", "♣️Q", "♣️J", "♣️10", "♣️9", "♣️8", "♣️7", "♣️6", "♣️5", "♣️4", "♣️3", "♣️2",
      "♥️A", "♥️K", "♥️Q", "♥️J", "♥️10", "♥️9", "♥️8", "♥️7", "♥️6", "♥️5", "♥️4", "♥️3", "♥️2",
      "♦️A", "♦️K", "♦️Q", "♦️J", "♦️10", "♦️9", "♦️8", "♦️7", "♦️6", "♦️5", "♦️4", "♦️3", "♦️2"]
combo = ["High card", "One pair", "Two pair",
     "Three of a Kind", "Straight", "Flush",
     "Full House", "Four of a Kind", "Straight Flush",
     "Royal Flush"]

Пример вывода кода:
Карты нейросети: ['♦️8', '♦️6']
Карты игрока: ['♠️9', '♠️6']
Раздача 1: ['♠️Q', '♥️8', '♣️4']
Использованные карты:  ['♦️8', '♦️6', '♠️9', '♠️6', '♠️Q', '♥️8', '♣️4']


Начните с малого, выберите 1 комбинацию к проверке и напишите для нее алгоритм. Потом для второй. И т.д.

Что значит "нельзя использовать функций Python"? Странная какая-то формулировка

@CrazyElf Покер будет на C# в WindowsForms, а на Python я пишу пример для себя, на что опираться. Поэтому нельзя использовать max, min и прочие, которых в C# нет

@Anteater_Corp В C# всё есть. Подключаете System.Linq и используете IEnumerable.Max и IEnumerable.Min.

@CrazyElf Спасибо, буду знать. Помогли
